# ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead insists after converting 1D array to 2D

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scikit-learn

I looked into other answers but still cannot understand why the problem insists.

Classic machine learning practice with Iris dataset.

Code:

```
dataset=load_iris()

X = np.array(dataset.data)
y = np.array(dataset.target)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3)

model = KNeighborsClassifier()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)

prediction=model.predict(X_test)
```

The shapes of all arrays:

1. X shape:  (150, 4)
2. y shape:  (150,)
3. X_train:  (105, 4)
4. X_test:  (45, 4)
5. y_train:  (105,)
6. y_test (45,)
7. prediction:  (45,)

Trying to print this **model.score(y_test, prediction)** and I get the error.
I tried to convert y_test and prediction into 2D arrays by using .reshape(-1,1) and I get another error: query data dimension must match training data dimension.

It's not only about the solution, it's about understanding what's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its often useful to look at the signature and docstrings for functions you use. `model.score` for example has

```
Parameters
----------
X : array-like, shape = (n_samples, n_features)
    Test samples.

y : array-like, shape = (n_samples) or (n_samples, n_outputs)
    True labels for X.
```

in the docstrings to show you the exact type of input you should give it.

Here you would do `model.score(X_test, y_test)`

`model.score` will do both the prediction from `X_test` and the comparison with `y_test`

Comment: What an unexpected problem I had. My mind was miles away. Thanks!